# Chrome Debugger (remote) won't expand elements, or objects output in console

Tags: 12.10, google-chrome, debugging

I am running chrome debugger remotely on an app I am building (appgyver, so javascript and HTML etc) and having real issues accessing the debugging data in the elements and console tabs.

For elements, it wont expand elements, or let me single left click on them to show me the styles in the right hand column.

In the console, if I `console.log(object)` in the code, then I can only expand the first level, and it won't let me delve any deeper.

I'm on Ubuntu 12.10, and Chrome Version 40.0.2214.94 (64-bit). This only happens if I use `chrome://inspect/#devices` and inspect from there. If I load the URL manually in a normal tab it works fine